# Using Jquery to load a reply form in a comment

Tags: jquery, load

```
 $('a.reply_links').bind('click', function(e) { 

  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#comment_results').load(url); 
  // load the html response into a DOM element
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the browser from following the link

  return false;
});
```

I have several comments on one page. All comments have a reply link. Each link when clicked goes to a php file where all comments are selected from a database and then loaded into the div (#comment_results). In addition the reply link that was clicked now contains a reply form.

The above code works fine when i click on one reply link. However, if i click another reply link on a different comment I am re-directed to the php file with the output. Html code is below. After clicking on the link the php file will add the reply form to that particular comment.

```
<div class="row">
<div id="comment_results" class="large-12 columns">

      <div class="panel"><div class="row" id="116">
      <div class="large-10 columns">
      <p>4 hours ago&nbsp;by&nbsp;<strong>Julian</strong>
      <br />Comment One</p></div>
      <div class="large-2 columns right">
      <a class="reply_links" href="mylink to php file">reply</a>
      </div></div></div>

      <div class="panel"><div class="row" id="115">
      <div class="large-10 columns">
      <p>5 hours ago&nbsp;by&nbsp;<strong>Julian</strong><br />
       Comment Two</p></div>
       <div class="large-2 columns right">
       <a class="reply_links" href="mylink to php file">reply</a>
      </div></div></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks Jillian

Comment: As Michael said, I've seen this happen when the container in the DOM gets removed (maybe after you close the reply message), so instead of loading the page contents into a container, it takes you to the actual page, or replaces the entire DOM with the new page.  My suggestion is to look through your "close" code and see if you're destroying/removing the container anywhere.

Comment: I checked the source code, still intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your query version is 1.7+ you could use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with delegated events as I imagine your problem is that you are clicking reply links created after original event bind.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.reply_links' function(e){ .. })
```

Comment: I am using jQuery v1.9.1. Tried the above code and now every link re-directs to my php file.

Answer (score 0):

If the `.reply_links` link is inside `#comment_results`, then it is getting replaced by the `.load()` call, so `.bind()` will only work the first time, when the page loads. The suggestion by Claudio is probably the easiest solution, if you're using the right version of jQuery. If that isn't an option, research [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/). Providing sample markup would also help in this case to determine the root cause of the problem.